# JAVA : file I/O

Tags: java, file-io, greedy

I have got two text files with data in the following format

`data.txt` file as following format

```
A 10
B 20
C 15
```

`data1.txt` file is in format (start node,end node, distance):

```
A B 5 
A C 10
B C 20
```

I am trying to implement a search strategy, for that I need to load the data from `data.txt` and ONLY the start node and end node from `data1.txt` (i.e. I dont need the distance). I need to store this information in a stack as I think it would be a best data structure for implementing greedy search.

Actually I am not sure how to get started with file I/O to read these files and store them in array to implement greedy search. So I would highly appreciate any starting idea on how to proceed.

I am new to this, so please bear with me. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT**:
Here is what I have got till now

```
String heuristic_file = "data.txt";
try
    {          

        FileReader inputHeuristic = new FileReader(heuristic_file);
        BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputHeuristic);
        String line;

        while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null)   
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        bufferReader.close(); 

    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: create a BufferedReader and use its readLine method to read the file line by line: `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(YOUR_FILE_PATH_HERE)))`; and then use `reader.readLine()`to read a line

Comment: Actually I know this, but I am not sure how to store it in a stack and particularly just the start and end node (not distance) from `data1.txt` file

Comment: @alainlompo I have added the code now. Please have a look.

Comment: I think first you need to read `data.txt`, remember what nodes you saw, and then read `data1.txt` line-by-line, and take only the line with the nodes you want.

Comment: Okay! but how do I keep those nodes in memory?

Comment: @Dee, thanks. What should you get after processing the two file? for A for example you would have stored in a stack (A, (A,B)) then (A, (A,C))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use split

```
            while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null)   
            {
                String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
                System.out.println(line + " -> [" + tokens[0] + "]" + "[" + tokens[1] + "][" + tokens[2] + "]");
            }
```

if you must have this in an array you can use the following:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NodeTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    try {          
      File first = new File("data.txt");
      File second = new File("data1.txt");    

      Node[] nodes1 =  getNodes(first);
      Node[] nodes2 =  getNodes(second);

      print(nodes1);
      print(nodes2);
    } 
    catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Error reading file " + e.getMessage());
    }   
  }

  public static final void print(Node[] nodes) {
    System.out.println("======================");
    for(Node node : nodes) {
      System.out.println(node);
    }
    System.out.println("======================");
  }

  public static final Node[] getNodes(File file) throws IOException {
    FileReader inputHeuristic = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputHeuristic);
    String line;
    List<Node> list = new ArrayList<Node>();
    while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
      String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
      list.add(new Node(tokens[0], tokens[1]));               
    }
    bufferReader.close(); 
    return list.toArray(new Node[list.size()]);
  } 
}

class Node {
  String start;
  String end;

  public Node(String start, String end){
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "[" + start + "][" + end + "]";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou! I found this simplest and easy to understand!

Answer (score 1):

My approach, doesn't differ fundamentally from the others. Please regard the try/catch/finally blocks. Always put the closing statements into the finally block, so the opened file is guaranteed to be closed, even if an exception was thrown while reading the file.

The part between the two //[...] could surely be done more efficient. Maybe reading the whole file in one take and then parsing the text backwards and searching for a line-break? Maybe a Stream-API supports to set the reading position. I honestly don't know. I didn't need that, up to now.

I chose to use the verbose initialization of the BufferedReader, because then you can specify the expected encoding of the file. In your case it doesn't matter, since your files do not contain symbols out of the standard ASCII range, but I believe it's a semi-best-practice.

Before you ask: `r.close()` takes care of closing the underlying `InputStreamReader` and `FileInputStream` in the right order, till all readers and streams are closed.

```
public static void readDataFile(String dir, String file1, String file2)
    throws IOException
{
    File datafile1 = new File(dir, file1);
    File datafile2 = new File(dir, file2);

    if (datafile1.exists())
    {
        BufferedReader r = null;

        try
        {
            r = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                    new FileInputStream(datafile1),
                    "UTF-8"
                )
            );

            String row;

            Stack<Object[]> s = new Stack<Object[]>();
            String[] pair;
            Integer datapoint;

            while((row = r.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (row != null && row.trim().length() > 0)
                {
                    // You could use " " instead of "\\s"
                    // but the latter regular expression
                    // shorthand-character-class will
                    // split the row on tab-symbols, too
                    pair = row.split("\\s");
                    if (pair != null && pair.length == 2)
                    {
                        datapoint = null;
                        try
                        {
                            datapoint = Integer.parseInt(pair[1], 10);
                        }
                        catch(NumberFormatException f) { }

                        // Later you can validate datapairs
                        // by using
                        // if (s.pop()[1] != null)
                        s.add(new Object[] { pair[0], datapoint});
                    }
                }
            }
       }
       catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) { }
       catch (FileNotFoundException e2) { }
       catch (IOException e3) { }
       finally
       {
           if (r != null) r.close();
       }
   }

   // Do something similar with datafile2
   if (datafile2.exists())
   {
       // [...do the same as in the first try/catch block...]

       String firstrow = null, lastrow = null;
       String row = null;
       int i = 0;
       do
       {
          lastrow = row;
          row = r.readLine();
          if (i == 0)
              firstrow = row;
          i++;
       } while(row != null);

       // [...parse firstrow and lastrow into a datastructure...]
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the `try catch` work, and the stream clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
HashSet<String> nodes = new HashSet<String>();
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt"))) {
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        String[] l = line.split(" ");
        nodes.add(l[0]);
        line = br.readLine();
    }
}

try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data1.txt"))) {
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        String[] l = line.split(" ");
        if (nodes.contains(l[0]) || nodes.contains(l[1]))
            // Do whatever you want ...
        line = br.readLine();
    }
}
```